# Converting URI (not URL) to UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using an api which returns a "uri" (not a url) for images. After storing the "uri" as a property of a local object, I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the "uri" string in order to convert it to a UIImage. Also if a bit more clarity can be shed on the difference between a url and uri that would be great.

[image: This is an example of the response from the server]

Comment: I would suggest to add the response example as code snippet instead of image.

Comment: What's the URL of the server?

Comment: This the URL http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings (an API Key is a required parameter)

Comment: `uri` is a relative `URL`. You need to compose the full URL (`[serverBaseURL] + uri`), load the data from the URL and create the image from the data.

Comment: Try adding that URI to the end of the URL of the api.

Comment: I guess it's a end path, and you need a baseURL, like "http://demo.tmsimg.com/" getting http://demo.tmsimg.com/assets/p12565017_p_v5_ae.jpg  Guessed from http://developer.tmsapi.com/page/Airing_Metadata but "demo" in the baseURL would maybe indicate it's not for release versions. I'd ask Gracenote how it really works or the server developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let uri = "assets/p12565017_p_v5_ae.jpg"

// The API documentation will tell you what the base URL is 
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://www.somewhere.com")! 
let imageURL = URL(string: uri, relativeTo: baseURL)!
```